# Website complains about your profile picture after you've submitted it and have an account

Tags: bug, profile-picture

I think I may have found a bug in the profile edit page and I want to report it so that the staff my have a look. For some reason my inverted PNG of au gratin potatoes was rejected when I used it as a profile pic during the initial sign up to the site process, yet when I tried to update my profile info the website decided (rightfully so I may add), that that picture is unsuitable for this forum:

[image: screenshot]

Anyways, I thought someone should know -- thanks for having me here.

Comment: ps it's still my picture :)

Comment: What could you possibly have against au gratin potatoes? They're *delicious*.

Comment: It accidentally displayed the wrong error message. It was actually just taking issue with your dislike of au gratin potatoes.

Comment: Hi, I have reworded the begin of the question to remove the "this is not a real question part": don't worry, we get bug reports all the time and posting a question is a way like any other to have the staff know (unless the bug is really bad, in which case it may be wise to contact them privately)

Comment: also, I haven't removed it, but the image seem to contain your birth date - you may want to hide it if you don't like to have it displayed.